# Why won't apt-get install anything after I deleted its cached lists?

Tags: apt, package-management

Recently I had a problem with the update-manager and search for a solution. On my search I found a post, where someone had the same problem and as solution they told him he should run this command on the terminal:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I also run this, and the update-manager worked again. But now, I noticed that apt-get won't install anything. I wanted to install rvm (for ruby) and therefore I needed a few packages (build-essential and curl to be precise). But if I tried to install them, I always get the message that there is no installcandidate for that package... .
What can I do to get apt-get working again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You deleted `apt-get`'s list of available packages, so it thinks that no packages exist and it is alone in this world :)

Just run `sudo apt-get update` to repopulate the lists, and then `sudo apt-get install ...` will work again.

Comment: I've done this, but nothing is changeing... . During the update, I got the message, that it couldn't find quite a few addresses. (e.g. http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.20 80]) May this be the reason? If so, what can I do to get those hosts working?

Comment: The 404s are occurring because `apt-get` is trying to find uncompressed `Packages` lists at the mirror when only compressed `Packages.bz2/gz` are available. Please run Software Center, Edit Preferences, and change your mirror to the default Main Server, and try again. If that doesn't work, can you copy and paste the output of `apt-config dump` please?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is working. I've changed the preferences and now I need to update a lot of packages. So, I guess, after the update is complete, apt-get will find my packages. Thx again :-)